# Specifying a "StructuredBuffer" as read-only in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm using structured buffers in HLSL code that I'm compiling for both D3D12 and Vulkan (the latter via SPIR-V). These buffers are intended to be read-only on the GPU. On D3D12, I'm getting expected results, but on Vulkan the only way I can see to bind them is as storage buffers, which according to what I'm seeing in RenderDoc are bound as read-write. This would match up with performance, where I'm seeing around a ~10% drop in performance on Vulkan compared to D3D12. Outside of this explicit case, D3D12 and Vulkan performance is generally identical (with Vulkan usually being slightly better by < 1% so effectively margin of error).

One solution here would be to just use a uniform texel buffer, since it's more explicit, but I do like the structured buffer pattern in the shader. So the question is - is there a way to use a Structured Buffer in Vulkan without the storage buffer read/write penalty? (I've tried binding descriptors as uniform buffer types, but the validation layer gets upset so clearly this isn't correct).

Edit: it turns out, the draw ordering in my (quite complex) test scene was dependent on the API being used. In the case of DX12, there was more early z-rejection, resulting in more efficiency. Once I fixed that, performance was comparable between the two. It was also interesting to note that the Vulkan path was more efficient, since I could use host-visible memory on the buffer and just call vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges, rather than doing the explicit buffer copy and memory barriers that's required on DX12.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what a "structured buffer" even is, but storage buffers can be read-only. You have to specify this in the shader, though.

Comment: Structured Buffer is an HLSL concept - you define the buffer as StructuredBuffer<type> where 'type' is a structure definition. Then you access buffer elements as you would an array. Looking at the disassembly in RenderDoc, it does look like it's specifying as read only in the shader. And switching to using a texel buffer which is definitely read-only, I see identical performance, which would imply that shader accesses to buffers in Vulkan are significantly slower than in Direct3D.

Comment: (By "identical performance" I mean the vulkan implementation is 10% or more slower than the identical workload on D3D12). This is probably something I'm doing wrong in Vulkan, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. But that's certainly a different question than the one I posted here.

Comment: Well, turns out, when draw-order is different between API implementations (as I just found out mine is), you get some big differences in performance. I fixed the draw ordering, and confirmed that performance is identical between API implementations.